# Wondering if there is a word for "Incompletely defined"?

Tags: phrases, terminology

No big deal if there does not exist such a word, but I was wondering.

Comment: Yeah. It's like when you start to define something and then ...

Comment: The question is rather nebulous without context. You could get any number of wishy-washy answers.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, the circumlocution *not [well defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined)* is the most common appellation for something that is incompletely defined ([1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Well-Defined.html), [2](http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/~larryc/proofs/proofs.welldefined.html)).  Occasionally  *[ambiguous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ambiguous#Adjective)* (“Open to multiple interpretations” or “Vague and unclear”) and *[ill-defined](http://thesaurus.com/browse/ill-defined)* are used as synonyms of *not well defined*.  Of *[ill-defined](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ill-Defined.html)*, mathworld says:  “The term "ill-defined" is also used informally to mean ambiguous.”